# create local ubuntu package repository

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, localrepository

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal) version and it is at EOL.

The repositories for older releases that are not supported get moved to an archive server. These repositories are available at `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com.`

Now I have to set up this repository on my local server so that we can fetch packages from it instead of archive server. For setting repository I am using [Apt-mirror](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/create-local-ubuntu-repository-using-apt-mirror-and-apt-cacher)

Currently my server is **Ubuntu 12.04** system and I have to set up repository for **Ubuntu 12.10**.

So I have following questions

- Is it possible to achieve above functionality?
- If I set up repository did it will affect on server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Your `mirror.list` will look something like this:

   ```
   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-i386 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-i386 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-i386 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security main restricted universe multiverse
   ```
2. Affect how? It will take a up a good bit of space (~100GB), and a good bit of bandwidth.